# Filter Java Object from Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, object, filter

I have a problem to filter in mongodb in my Java Application.
My collection has entries like the following one:

*{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5228388f12ca90cecddbce98"} , "User" : { "name" : "Name" , "password" : "Password"}}*

Now I want to get a User with the name "Name". I tried it with this code, but it didn't work.

```
BasicDBObject object = new BasicDBObject("User", new BasicDBObject("name", "Name"));
```

It works fine if I try it like this:

```
BasicDBObject object = new BasicDBObject("User", new BasicDBObject("name", "Name").append("password", "Password"));
```

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter on nested property, you need to access the property using `.`:

```
BasicDBObject object = new BasicDBObject("User.name", "Name");
```